# Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3 \sin^2n}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this series given by $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3 \sin^2n}.$$
I know that the terms are all nonnegative. Can I get a subsequence of $\frac{1}{n^3 \sin^2n}$ such that its sum diverges to $+\infty$?

Comment: [Flint Hills series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FlintHillsSeries.html)? The question is open, depending on [irrationality measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) of $\pi$

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24579/convergence-of-sumn3-sin2n-1

Comment: Alright. I see!